# Send touch events from Mac OSX application to USB connected iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, usb

I have a requirement that, I need to test a iOS app from remote machine. Flow is follows :

1. Connect iPhone/iPad to any Mac OS system.
2. Create a Mac OSX application which can read my USB connected iOS device and show its screen when run the OSX application (Like mirroring).
3. Select any iOS app installed in USB connected iOS device and interact with that using OSX application.

Can someone please help me , is it possible with Mac OSX `ioKit` framework ?

Comment: found a solution?

Comment: nope, due to apple security constraints we can't get this done.

Answer (score -6):

Yes, it's possible, but it requires a lot of work, and I won't provide code here. We have implemented this feature in our VMLite VNC Server.

Comment: While this does, strictly speaking, answer the question "is it possible," it's not a useful answer – -1.

Comment: It also looks like the iOS version of the product is hard to find, only found it by searching the product name with "iOS" and only this page came up with it: http://www.vmlite.com/purchase.html, no trial version then?

Comment: With iOS 13, this becomes much easier to implement. It seems Apple finally publicly allows HID devices to connect to iOS 13 via USB or Bluetooth. I've done some android apps to verify this.

Comment: I can't give the answer explicitly because it uses some undocumented method, which not good to disclose.